# mouseout keep div showing until next rollover

Tags: mouseover, mouseout

Using the following code, how can I keep the div open and not hidden once the mouse roll off the trigger, until another trigger is rolled over?

I am using this code on http://griffithsandpartners.com.gridhosted.co.uk/services-3/ the Customer wants a rollover action on the services button, but as they have a lot of text with some of them, you can't scroll down to view it without coming off the trigger, and then it's hidden.

They don't want a click to open.

Really appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be is that you remove the `onmouseout` of all `pop-up-triggers` and you set a `onmouseout=document.getElementById('ALL-THE-POP-UP-BOX').style.display = 'none';` to the div with the `class="postcontent clearfix"`

like so:

`<div class="postcontent clearfix" onmouseout=document.getElementById('ALL-THE-POP-UP-BOX').style.display = 'none';>`

So when the mouse leaves the `pop-up-triggers` it wont hide the `pop-up-box` but if the mouse leaves the postcontent clearfix div it will hide all displayed pop-up-box.

Note: you have to hide all `pop-up-box` on `pop-up-trigger mouseover` so that only the current pop-up-box will be displayed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. that helps allot. Really appreciate your time on this. :-)

Comment: @LyndsayMoon No Prob! BTW if this helped you pls. check my answer so that others will know that this question has been answered.